# How to scrape image/file from web page in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, urlopen

I try to use Python3.7.4 to backup pictures in a blog site, e.g. 
   http://s2.sinaimg.cn/mw690/001H6t4Fzy7zgC0WLXb01&690
If I input the above address in Firefox address bar, the file is shown correctly.
If I use following code to download picture, server always redirects to a default picture:

```
from requests import get # just to try different methods
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, quote

# hard-coded address is randomly selected for debug purpose.
origPict = 'http://s2.sinaimg.cn/mw690/001H6t4Fzy7zgC0WLXb01&690' 
p = urlsplit (origPict)
newP = quote (p.path)
origPict = urlunsplit ([p.scheme, p.netloc, newP, p.query, p.fragment])

try:
  #url_file = urlopen(origPict)
  #u = url_file.geturl ()
  url_file = get (origPict)
  u = url_file.url
  if u != origPict:
    raise Exception ('Failed to get picture ' + origPict)
...
```

Any clue why requests.get or urllib.urlopen don't like '&' in url?

Updates: Thanks for Artur's comments, I realize the question is not on request itself, but on site protection mechanism: js or cookies or something else in webpage feedback something to server to allow it to judge if request comes from scraper. So now the question turns to how to scrape image from web page which is more complex than simply download image from url.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about & symbol, but about redirection. Try adding parameter allow_redirects=False to get, it should be okay

Comment: By adding that parameter, server returns a html page saying: "302 Found" and "The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI." If don't add that parameter, the history part says "302".

Comment: After further try, I think it's not redirection related. Without allow_redirects=False, the url_file.url is redirected url (url1) and url_file.history[0].url is original url (url0); with allow_redirects=False, url_file.url is url0 with url_file.is_redirect=True and url_file.next.url is url1. So finally both methods get same file.